# Pass .Range as a parameter VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

Hi Please help me with the below,

```
Sub movedata()

    Call select_data(.Range("B6:B12"))


End Sub


Function select_data(C As Range)

    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("I6:I16") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(C).Value

End Function
```

I can't see where I am going wrong,

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C` already is a `Range` object so there's no need to pass it to the `Range()` function (which expects a string anyway) to create it.

Change:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("I6:I16") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(C).Value
```

To:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("I6:I16") = C
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still getting an error for .range("B6:B16") when I call secect_data....

Invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: You're using a `.` before `.Range(...)` which I assumed was because you had a `With Sheets(...)` block that you just weren't showing. If you want to pass a range from the active sheet, just remove the `.` when you pass your range. Otherwise, prefix it with your sheet name: `Call select_data(Sheets("mysheet").Range("B6:B12"))`.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the range as a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) with its [Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx).

Method 1:

```
Sub movedata()
    Call select_data(Range("B6:B12").address)
End Sub

Function select_data(C As string)
    with Worksheets("sheet1")
        .Range("I6:I16") = .Range(C).Value
    end with
End Function
```

Method 2:

```
Sub movedata()
    Call select_data(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B6:B12"))
End Sub

Function select_data(C As range)
    C.parent.Range("I6").resize(C.rows.count, C.columns.count) = C.Value
End Function
```

fwiw, there is going to be some difficulties stuffing B6:B12's values into I6:I16's cells. There seem to be 4 missing values.